# How to get one element from 3 elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, record

I have three elements in value of **pay[]** at

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="pay[]"  value="
               <?php 
                     echo $invoiceArr[$record_count].";";
                     echo $TotalArr[$record_count].";";
                     echo $amount_dueArr[$record_count];
                  ?>
                  "  onClick="checkTotal()"/>
           </td>
```

And I want to use

```
   echo $amount_dueArr[$record_count];
```

only inside var elements:
may be something like?

```
   var elements = document.getElementsByName("pay[][2]");


    function checkTotal() 
 {
       var sum = 0;
       var elements = document.getElementsByName("pay[]");
 }
```

Is it possible ?
Do I make myself clear ?

Thank you all guys...

complete javascript function

```
function checkTotal() {
                            document.payform.totalNS.value = '';

                            var sum = 0;
                            var pay_amt_no_id = document.payform.pay_amt_noDocID_textbox.value;
                            //var elements = document.getElementsByName("pay[]");

                            var amount_due = <?php echo $amount_dueArr[$record_count]; ?>, // no quotes
                            var  sum = 0, // using 1 var statement for declarations.
                            var  elements = [];
                            var  elements = document.getElementsByName("pay[]").value.split(";");
                           // pay[] is invoice_num;total;amount_due.
                           return elements.length===3 && amount_due == elements[2]; // counting on 
                          // string to num conversion here



                            document.payform.pay_amt_noDocID_checkbox.value = pay_amt_no_id;

                            document.payform.totalNS.value = sum;
                            for (i=0;i < elements.length;i++) {
                                  if (elements[i].checked) {
                                 sum = sum + +elements[i].value;

                          }
                        }
```

Comment: Ummmm. what? This makes no sense...

Comment: not possible or any ideas on how to retrieve it ?

Comment: More like I have no idea what you're trying to ask. How about showing a sample of the HTML you're trying to create. You're mixing PHP and Javascript, and not explaining the HOW/WHY, just "here's some random code snippets".

Comment: You'll need to do some debugging using firebug or other. Check out the values of your variables. Step through the function to see what is going on. Also you probably do not want the return statement there since the function ends when it hits the return statement.

Answer (score 1):

It is fine to mix php and Javascript as you're doing. The trick is to always remember that the php code's output will be a *constant* from the point of view of the Javascript code.

And that a Javascript constant needs to be coded correctly, quoted appropriately for strings, but not for numbers, etc.

I usually use my server side language to create the arguments for Javascript function calls. -- Creating server-side content in the middle of a chunk of Javascript can be confusing to read and result in brittle code.

Note that your question says `I have three elements in value of pay[] at` Well, not quite. In Javascript/DOM land You're setting pay[] to a single string that includes semicolons. I'd write the code as:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="pay[]"  
   value="<?php echo $invoiceArr[$record_count].";".$TotalArr[$record_count].
                  ";".$amount_dueArr[$record_count]; ?>"
   onClick="checkTotal()"/>
</td>
```

To make it a little more clear that you're supplying one string value to the input element.

**Re: And I want to use**

```
echo $amount_dueArr[$record_count];
```

....

Sure, no problem. Eg:

```
function checkTotal() 
 {
   var amount_due = <?php echo $amount_dueArr[$record_count]; ?>, // no quotes
       sum = 0, // using 1 var statement for declarations.
       elements = [];
   elements = document.getElementsByName("pay[]").value.split(";");
   // pay[] is invoice_num;total;amount_due.
   return elements.length===3 && amount_due == elements[2]; // counting on 
                                                // string to num conversion here
 }
```

But rather than this solution, I'd recommend that you assign the php-generated amount_due to a Javascript variable at the top of the html page. Burying the echo command into the middle of a function will work but is not good style.

Comment: how to do it ? `// string to num conversion here`

Comment: Right--a floating point number needs explicit conversion. So try... amount_due == parseFloat(elements[2]);

Comment: `return elements.length===3 && amount_due == parseFloat(elements[2]);`

Comment: this is in <input...    `<input type="checkbox" onclick="checkTotal()" value=" CINV159092;978.56;978.56 " name="pay[]">` I want to use only the third value

Comment: not working yet return elements.length===3 && amount_due == parseFloat(elements[2]);

Comment: the function is not working...how can I parse 1 element from 3 elements ? thanks

Comment: The split works fine, I just tested it. The problem, therefore, is in the `document.getElementsByName("pay[]").value` Try adding an alert to see what value is being returned from that statement.